# Not able to setValue in useState in React Material-UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I have created a custom dialog component in Material-UI

```
const CustomDialog = (props) => {

  const [dialogOpenState, setOpen] = React.useState(props.dilaogOpenProp);

  return (
    <>
      <CssBaseline />
      <Dialog
        fullWidth
        onClose={() => {}}
        open={dialogOpenState}
        maxWidth="xs"
        sx={{
          backdropFilter: "blur(5px)",
        }}
      >
        <DialogTitle>Example Dialog</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>Example Content Here</DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button>ooooh.</Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
      <Box
        sx={{
          minHeight: "100vh",
          background:
            "url(https://source.unsplash.com/random) no-repeat center center",
          backgroundSize: "cover",
        }}
      ></Box>
    </>
  );
}


export default CustomDialog;
```

I am trying this to manage open close from another component using `useState`

```
const Minidrawer = props => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const { history } = props;
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const [dialogOpen,setDialogueOpen] = React.useState(false)

  const handleDialogueOpen = () => {
    console.log("clicked");
    setDialogueOpen(true)
  }

  return (
    <Box sx={{ display: 'flex' }}>
      
      <AppBar position="fixed" open={open}>

        <Toolbar>
          <Typography variant="h6" noWrap component="div">
            COMPANY NAME
          </Typography>
          <Button onClick={handleDialogueOpen}>Filter</Button>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      


      <CustomDialog dilaogOpenProp={dialogOpen}/>

    </Box>
  );
}

export default withRouter(Minidrawer);
```

I am trying to set **`dialogOpen`** which is getting passed in Dialog open prop value to false using **`useState`** ,I am getting clicked in console but dilaog not getting invoked, also if I manually set the **`dialogOpen`** in **`useState`** its working but not on click, what's going on here?

Comment: There is a typo in `dilaogOpenProp` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the state from the child component get updated based on the prop provided from the parent, you can use `useEffect`. You're passing the prop to `useState` in the child component (`React.useState(props.dilaogOpenProp)`) which only works in the first render:

```
const [dialogOpenState, setOpen] = React.useState(props.dilaogOpenProp);

useEffect(() => {
  // update the state every time the prop.dilaogOpenProp dependency changes
  setOpen(props.dilaogOpenProp);
}, [props.dilaogOpenProp]);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're copying props to state within `CustomDialog`. That means that changes to `dilaogOpenProp` in the parent are ignored by `CustomDialog`. (This is generally [not best practice](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#when-to-use-derived-state), but there are edge cases where it can make sense.) Since you're doing that, `CustomDialog` only uses the **initial** value of that prop, not the updated value when your parent component changes it. Here's a simpler example demonstrating that:

```js
const {useState} = React;

const Child = (props) => {
    const [childValue, setChildValue] = useState(props.parentValue);
    return <div>
        <div><code>props.parentValue = {String(props.parentValue)}</code></div>
        <div><code>childValue = {String(childValue)}</code></div>
    </div>;
};

const Parent = () => {
    const [parentValue, setParentValue] = useState(false);

    const toggleParentValue = () => setParentValue(v => !v);

    return <div>
        <Child parentValue={parentValue} />
        <div>
            <button onClick={toggleParentValue}>
                Toggle <code>parentValue</code>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

You need to *either* store the open/closed state in the parent and have the parent control it, *or* store the open/closed state in `CustomDialog` and have `CustomDialog` control it. You can't do both.

Often that means having the parent be in control, but passing a function to the child that the child can use to tell the parent about a change. For instance, if you need `CustomDialog` to be able to close itself (fairly common with dialogs), you can pass it a function the parent provides that does that.

Answer (score 0):

You must keep the state updated, use `useState`:

```
const CustomDialog = ({ dilaogOpenProp }) => {
  const [dialogOpenState, setOpen] = React.useState(dilaogOpenProp);

    useEffect(() => {
        setOpen(props.dialogOpenState);
    }, [dilaogOpenProp])
  );
}
```

You can also **get the value directly from props**

```
<Dialog open={props.dilaogOpenProp}>
    ...
</Dialog>
```